# Getting serial number from Host Inventory with Zabbix API (python)

Tags: python, api, zabbix

I'm trying to fetch a seriel number of a router with Zabbix API. I use the following code:

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI

username = "myuser"
password = "mypasswd"
servername = "https://10.10.1.1/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php"

zapi = ZabbixAPI(servername)
zapi.session.verify = False
zapi.login(username, password)

payload = {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "method": "host.get",
                "params": {
                        "output": [
                                "host"
                        ],
                        "selectInventory": [
                                "serialno_a"
                        ],
                        "searchInventory": {
                                "oob_ip": "174.145.27.15"
                        }
                },
                "id": 2
        }


hosts = zapi.host.get(payload)
print(hosts)
```

So, this code prints every single host in my Zabbix and every single item property in **host** object. What I want, is to print a value that is a property in **host inventory** object. Also, I want to restrict my code only to fetch the serial number associated with that IP address of 174.145.27.15. As far as I can understand, this code should do that.

And below is the example syntax from Zabbix API's official reference.

*Searching by host inventory data*

*Retrieve hosts that contain “Linux” in the host inventory “OS” field.*

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.get",
    "params": {
        "output": [
            "host"
        ],
        "selectInventory": [
            "os"
        ],
        "searchInventory": {
            "os": "Linux"
        }
    },
    "id": 2,
    "auth": "7f9e00124c75e8f25facd5c093f3e9a0"
}
```

And below is the link to the official API documentation, where you can see properties of **host** and **host inventory**

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/host/object

I'm really lost here and can't find any help by googling around. Also, I don't really understand what is the point of that **"id": 2** because I get the same result no matter what the value is.

Comment: Such a request works just fine for me, even with the exact same inventory fields. What's your exact Zabbix version? Also, please show the raw JSON send to the API, maybe some formatting is wrong there.

Comment: @Richlv I'm using 3.2. I couldn't make it work with that code. In the documentation there's a statement that an authentication token is needed in order to get it work. So I re-wrote my code, first fetching the token and then using that token to fetch the data I wanted and it works perfectly. I don't know if 3.2 allows accessing data using pyzabbix at all, since the token must be present. So my new code was based on requests module,

Comment: `zapi.login` was supposed to log in, get the token for you and then use it in subsequent requests. As you were getting the host data, that had worked and token missing was not the problem.